# ReferenceError when trying to access Backbone models from Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I think this is just a JavaScript scope question.

I'm trying to add some Jasmine tests to a Backbone application, but I can't figure out how to access Backbone models from within my Jasmine setup.

This is my current application structure (`main.js` is my Backbone application):

```
index.html
js/
  main.js
  vendor/
    backbone.js
    jquery.min.js // etc  
tests/
  SpecRunner.html
  spec/
    testSpec.js
```

The content of `main.js` is like this, and it's all running OK from `index.html`:

```
$(function(){
  var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
      return {};
    }, 
 ... etc
```

The files in SpecRunner.html look like this:

```
  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/testSpec.js"></script>
```

I have written this test in `testSpec.js`, but it's failing with `ReferenceError: Todo is not defined`:

```
describe("Todo tests", function(){ 
  var todo = new Todo("Get the milk", "Tuesday"); 
  it("should be correctly defined", function(){
    expect(todo).toBeDefined();
  });
  it("should have the correct title", function(){
    expect(todo.title).toBe("Get the milk");
  });
});
```

How can I get hold of the Todo scope? I've tried `window.Todo` but that doesn't help either.

Comment: could you please test using Setup and Tear Down http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Setup_and_Teardown

Comment: You need to fix this `Todo("Get the milk", "Tuesday");` to `Todo({"task":"Get the milk","date":"Tuesday");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can see at the [Backbone reference](http://backbonejs.org/#Model).

> **constructor / initialize** `new Model([attributes], [options])`
>   When creating an instance of a model, you can pass in the initial values of
>   the attributes, which will be set on the model.

The constructor needs to be initilized with a object literal(Key value pair), as follow:

```
new Book({
    title: "One Thousand and One Nights",
    author: "Scheherazade"
});
```

So you need to change your code to:

```
var todo = new Todo({   
                 task: "Get the milk",
                 dayOfWeek: "Tuesday"
           });
```

**UPDATE:**

Here you declared the Todo inside the jquery function scope and you're trying to access from outside.

```
$(function(){
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function() {
          return {};
        },
        etc...
    } 
}
```

You have two options, declare Todo as global, not recommend, but largely used at backbone samples:

```
$(function(){
    window.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function() {
          return {};
        },
        etc...
    } 
});
```

You could also try to call the jquery function after declaration:

```
$(function(){
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function() {
          return {};
        },
        etc...
    } 
})();
```

Comment: Nope, still `ReferenceError: Todo is not defined`. I think you're right that the object should be constructed in that way, but at the moment the problem is simply that Jasmine can't see any `Todo` at all.